# vim +Syntastic mapping keys to :SyntasticChecking doesn't work

Tags: vim, syntastic

I tried mapping the key to `:SyntasticCheck` of Syntastic vim in `.vimrc`

```
nmap <leader>sc :SyntasticCheck<CR>
```

but it doesn't work. Also, when I type this command `:SyntasticCheck` into vim command it doesn't work, but when I save file with `:w` it works. It checks the syntax & raise errors in bottom window.

Any Ideas?

Comment: if it does not work, it means that Syntastic is not properly installed.

Comment: Both seem to work fine on my machine.  What did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?  What is the output of `:nmap <leader>sc`?  Does your `nmap` gets executed before or after syntastic is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Syntastic runs the checker on the current file, *not* the contents of the buffer. If you have a file without syntax errors, add a syntax error, but don't save the file, `:SyntasticCheck` will not mark the error because you haven't saved the file. Your mapping is probably working fine, but nothing is getting marked by Syntastic because you haven't saved the file.